# Why my regexp not working in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

lines:

```
<option value="148">&nbsp; Подарки, сувениры</option>
<option value="96">&nbsp; Товары для дома</option>
```

I would like find thyes in notepad++ with find with regexp, for this i use regexp:

```
/<option value=\"\d{1,3}\">/g
```

[image]

But i get **0** matches...

I check regexp on online tester and see that it work:
[image]

***But why my regexp not working in notepad++ ?***

Comment: Why do you have `/ ... /g` in notepad++? Remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/.../flags` is the JavaScript regexp literal notation. The *real* regexp actually is what's inbetween the two `/`, i.e. in your case `<option value=\"\d{1,3}\">`.

Side note: no need to escape the `"` in this case: `<option value="\d{1,3}">`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Jerry wrote in his comment: /..../g is JavaScript regular expressions notation.
I checked in Notepad++ and `<option value=\"\d{1,3}\">` works.